# An html form which auto detects the input and change an image accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need an html form in which if we type in a field with a number starting with "3",an image "visa" should be shown and if it starts with 9,it will show mastercard.It can be done using java script but I dont know how.Can some one help me.

```
function handleEvent(event)
{
  var value   = event.target.value,    
      type    = getCreditCardType(value);

  switch (type)
  {
    case "mastercard":
        //show MasterCard icon
        break;

    case "visa":
        //show Visa icon
        break;

    case "amex":
        //show American Express icon
        break;

    default:
        //clear all icons?
        //show error?
  }
}

// or window.onload
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var textbox = document.getElementById("cc-num");
  textbox.addEventListener("keyup", handleEvent, false);
  textbox.addEventListener("blur", handleEvent, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: I have this function.But I dont know how I should show the image

Comment: @Ajeesh Achuthan you should read Rules before posting any such question here...now in this edit you have posted the code which looks like a good question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eK59U/)

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#my_id').keyup(function(){
                if(this.value != '' ){
                    var val = this.value.substring(0,1);
                    if(val == '3'){
                        alert('visa card');
                    }else if(val == '9'){
                        alert('master card');
                    }else{
                        alert('other value');
                    }

                }
            })
        });
```

**HTML CODE**

```
    <input type="text" id="my_id" value="" />
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var num2img = {
  "3" : "visa",
  "9" : "mastercard"
};

$('#num').on('input', function(){
  var n = this.value.charAt(0);  
  if(n && n in num2img){
    $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'images/'+ num2img[n] +'.png';
  }else{
    $('#cardImage')[0].src = 'images/cardImage.png'; // default
  }
});
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/OdeHeju/8/edit)

Comment: @AjeeshAchuthan you're welcome. I'd also add an `if` to do this check only if the `this.value.length` is `<=1`. We don't need it for every character we hit, just for the first one. http://jsbin.com/OdeHeju/5/edit and probably would also be helpful to prevent other non-numeric characters. But that's another question ;)

Comment: Yes.I have done that :) You are cool man.This was really helpful